# Azure blob storage SAS

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

How to grant temporary privileges to download one blob in Azure blob storage via a SAS, that has a duration equivalent to the period of time the download will take. i.e. privilege will be no longer than necessary?

Comment: There will be a charge every time a client downloads the blob, what if user downloads 10 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible by design, you can grant a short lived SAS token (e.g. 1 minute) but if the client is on a slow internet connection that could be a problem.
What is the problem if the client downloads the blob multiple times? sometimes a user "loses" a file and redownloads the same file. Why do you want this?

If the download is handled by an application, you could use a `stored access policy`, and after the client succesfully downloads the file, removes the policy so the SAS is revoked:
https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/

Comment: Depends on the use case, you may only want the user to be able to download the blob once especially as each download is chargeable.

Comment: Good point, but the download is charged per 4MB block being downloaded. Multi threaded downloads are allowed,and retries per block are also allowed. So it will be very difficult to enforce this.